# Rails - Keep a table out of structure.sql during migrations

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

It is straightforward to ignore tables when your schema format is `:ruby`, but is there a way to do it when your schema format is `:sql`?

Ideally something like this in `environment.rb`:

```
ActiveRecord::SQLDumper.ignore_tables = ['table_name']
```

After a quick perusal through the AR source code it looks unpromising.

Answer (score 5):

There is currently no way to do this, when the schema format is set to `:sql`, Rails doesn't go through the regular `SchemaDumper` but instead uses the tasks in `ActiveRecord::Tasks::PostgreSQLDatabaseTasks` to do the dump, [check it out here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/tasks/postgresql_database_tasks.rb#L45).

The code is quite straightforward. I came up with a simple patch for `ActiveRecord` that should work as expected. It relies on setting the tables to ignore in your `database.yml` file. It basically adds the following code:

```
ignore_tables = configuration['ignore_tables']
unless ignore_tables.blank?
  args += ignore_tables.split(',').map do |table|
    "-T #{table}"
  end
end
```

I just submitted [a pull request to rails](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/24714) with those changes. In case you'd want to test it.

Answer (score 5):

For the sake of people landing here after Googling this problem in 2022: As of [this PR](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/29077) the `structure.sql` dump should respect the `ignore_tables` configuration of `ActiveRecord::SchemaDumper`. If you're using a regular `schema.rb`, this option can be a mix of strings and regexes; However, if you're using a `structure.sql`, it will only take strings [according to the docs](https://apidock.com/rails/v6.1.3.1/ActiveRecord/SchemaDumper/ignore_tables/class).

In any case, you can add an initializer to modify the list of ignored tables however you need. In my case, I have a number of backup tables that are created when certain risky operations are performed, and I'd like to exclude those from the `structure.sql`. Adding this initializer solved it for me:

```rb
# config/initializers/ignore_tables.rb

backup_tables = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables.select do |t|
  t.match?(/_backup_.*$/)
end

ActiveRecord::SchemaDumper.ignore_tables += backup_tables
```